# Hello, I tried convert string value from my database to int, but it didn't happen

Tags: java, android, database, type-conversion

## This fragment of code have to count "imt" value, using two (String)values from my database. But my program crashes, I gave your my Logcat below! I think, i wrong in Integer conversion.

```
public class ScheduleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    DataBaseHelper myDb;
    Button mon_tue,wed_th,fri_sat;
    TextView result_title,result_warm_up,result_one,result_two,result_three,result_four,result_five,result_six,result_seven;
    long imt;
    String name;
    String age;
    String weight;
    String height;
    String gender;
    String trauma;
    String illnesses;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
        /*DataBase*/
        myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);
        /*Buttons*/
        mon_tue = (Button) findViewById(R.id.mon_tue);
        wed_th = (Button) findViewById(R.id.wed_th);
        fri_sat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.fri_sat);
        /*TEXTVIEWS*/
        result_title = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_title);
        result_warm_up = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_warm_up);
        result_one = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_one);
        result_two = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_two);
        result_three = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_three);
        result_four = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_four);
        result_five = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_five);
        result_six = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_six);
        result_seven = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.result_seven);
        /*read data*/
        Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
        if(res!=null&&res.getCount()>0){
            while (res.moveToNext()){
                name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("NAME"));
                age = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("AGE"));
                weight = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("WEIGHT"));
                height = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("HEIGHT"));
                gender = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("GENDER"));
                trauma = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("TRAUMA"));
                illnesses = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("ILLNESSES"));
                /*IMT(imt) - Brain of my App*/
                int height_int = Integer.parseInt(height.trim());
                int weight_int = Integer.parseInt(weight.trim());
                imt = ((weight_int/(height_int*height_int))*10000);
                /*It is the end of brain opportunities*/
                if(imt<18.5){

                    result_title.setText(R.string.hi+", "+R.string.name);
                    result_warm_up.setText(R.string.warm_up);
                    result_one.setText(R.string.abdominal_muscles+" "+name);
                    result_two.setText(R.string.the_dumbbell_fly+" "+"");
                    result_three.setText(R.string.extension_of_the_trunk+" "+"");
                    result_four.setText(R.string.hand_dumbbell_side_lift+" "+"");
                    result_five.setText(R.string.pull_up+" "+"");
                    result_six.setText(R.string.pullover+" "+"");
                }
                if(imt==0){
                    result_title.setText(R.string.data);
                }
            }
        }else{
            result_title.setText(R.string.result_wrong);
        }

    }

}
```

## My logcat!

```
/myway E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: adais.myway, PID: 30254
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{adais.myway/myway.ScheduleActivity}: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2338)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641)
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""
        at java.lang.Integer.invalidInt(Integer.java:137)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:358)
        at java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:331)
        at adais.myway.ScheduleActivity.onCreate(ScheduleActivity.java:58)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5264)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1088)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2302)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1321) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:825) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:641) 
        at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

## I think my database is not correct?

```
public class DataBaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Schedule.dp";
    public static final String TABLE_NAME = "Schedule_table";
    /*Col*/
    public static final String COL_1 = "ID";
    public static final String COL_2 = "NAME";
    public static final String COL_3 = "AGE";
    public static final String COL_4 = "WEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_5 = "HEIGHT";
    public static final String COL_6 = "GENDER";
    public static final String COL_7 = "TRAUMA";
    public static final String COL_8 = "ILLNESSES";

    public DataBaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,1);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
        db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE "+TABLE_NAME+" (ID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,NAME TEXT,AGE INTEGER,WEIGHT INTEGER,HEIGHT INTEGER,GENDER TEXT,TRAUMA TEXT,ILLNESSES TEXT)");
    }
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion){
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS "+ TABLE_NAME);
    }

    public boolean updataData(String id,String name,String age,String weight,String height,String gender,String trauma,String illnesses){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,age);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,weight);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,height);
        contentValues.put(COL_6,gender);
        contentValues.put(COL_7,trauma);
        contentValues.put(COL_8,illnesses);
        int result = db.update(TABLE_NAME,contentValues,"ID =?",new String[]{id});
        if (result>0){
            return true;
        }else{
            return false;
        }

    }
    public boolean insertData(String name,String age,String weight,String height,String gender,String trauma,String illnesses){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
        contentValues.put(COL_2,name);
        contentValues.put(COL_3,age);
        contentValues.put(COL_4,weight);
        contentValues.put(COL_5,height);
        contentValues.put(COL_6,gender);
        contentValues.put(COL_7,trauma);
        contentValues.put(COL_8,illnesses);
        long result = db.insert(TABLE_NAME,null,contentValues);
        db.close();
        if (result==-1){
            return false;
        }else{
            return true;
        }

    }
    public Cursor getAllData(){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor res = db.rawQuery("Select * from "+ TABLE_NAME,null);
        return res;
    }
}
```

## And my main activity

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
    DataBaseHelper myDb;
    EditText name_edittext,age_edittext,weight_edittext,height_edittext;
    Spinner gender_spinner,trauma_spinner,illnesses_spinner;
    Button save,test_b;
    String name;
    TextView test;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        /*DataBase*/
        myDb = new DataBaseHelper(this);

        test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.test_text);
        test_b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.test);
        test_b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                test();
            }
        });

        /*Spinners*/
        gender_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_gender);
        trauma_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_trauma);
        illnesses_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_illnesses);

        String [] gender={"Male","Female"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> gender_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,gender);
        gender_spinner.setAdapter(gender_adapter);
        String [] trauma={"Back","Hand","Leg"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> trauma_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,trauma);
        trauma_spinner.setAdapter(trauma_adapter);
        String [] illnesses={"Yes","None"};
        ArrayAdapter<String> illnesses_adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item,illnesses);
        illnesses_spinner.setAdapter(illnesses_adapter);
        /*EditTexts*/
        name_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
        age_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.age);
        weight_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.weight);
        height_edittext = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.height);
        /*Button*/
        save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save_button);
        /*Save*/
        save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ClickMe();
            }
        });
    }

    private void ClickMe(){
        String name = name_edittext.getText().toString();
        String age = age_edittext.getText().toString();
        String weight = weight_edittext.getText().toString();
        String height = height_edittext.getText().toString();
        String gender = gender_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String trauma = trauma_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        String illnesses = illnesses_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString();
        Boolean result = myDb.insertData(name,age,weight,height,gender,trauma,illnesses);
        if (result == true){
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data is added successfully",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data is not added",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        Intent i = new Intent(this,MenuActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

    }
    public void test(){
        Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
        if(res!=null&&res.getCount()>0){
            while (res.moveToNext()){
                name = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("NAME"));

            }
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data is read",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else{
            Toast.makeText(this,"Data is unread",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
        test.setText(name);


    }
}
```

## At the end my layout of Schedule #

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".ScheduleActivity">
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/mon_tue"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0091EA"
            android:text="@string/mon_tue"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/wed_th"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0091EA"
            android:text="@string/wed_th"/>
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/fri_sat"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#0091EA"
            android:text="@string/fri_sat"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:layout_margin="20dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/result_title"
        android:textSize="26dp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        android:text="@string/result_wrong"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/result_warm_up"
        android:textSize="26dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/result_one"
        android:textSize="26dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/result_two"
        android:textSize="26dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/result_three"
        android:textSize="26dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/result_four"
        android:textSize="26dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/result_five"
        android:textSize="26dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/result_six"
        android:textSize="26dp"/>
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/result_seven"
        android:textSize="26dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: What an awful lot of code to expect us to pick through. `java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid int: ""`. You are trying to convert an empty string to an int.

Comment: How to change it in my code(I'm a newer)?

Comment: Don't post code in comments. [Edit] the question.

Comment: I tried to write "if(zero)" but it didn't help me

Comment: The fact that you're trying to write and read int columns as strings makes me suspicious. Try reading them as ints.

Comment: Such like res.getString but res.getInt? It doesn't work because i use String value of those values in my database

Comment: error: incompatible types: String cannot be converted to Integer

Answer (score 1):

```
Cursor res = myDb.getAllData();
     if(res!=null&&res.getCount()>0){
          while (res.moveToNext()){
               weight = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("WEIGHT"));
               height = res.getString(res.getColumnIndex("HEIGHT"));

Log.i("Weight", weight);
Log.i("Height", height);
```

Add a log here and check what output is shown in logcat ? I think it is fetching null values.

Comment: I have a lot of values from my last adding to database.Not zero

Comment: Please send the screenshot of the value of weight and height shown in logcat

Comment: 06-09 23:53:06.865 32253-32253/adais.myway I/Weight: 65

Comment: 06-09 23:53:06.865 32253-32253/adais.myway I/Height: 185

Comment: 06-09 23:53:06.866 32253-32253/adais.myway I/Weight: 68

Comment: 06-09 23:53:06.866 32253-32253/adais.myway I/Height: 185

Comment: It's my screenshot))

Comment: So, it is successfully fetching the data from database. There might be a logical error. First try to typecase the result in long.

imt = ((long)(weight_int/(height_int*height_int))*10000);

Answer (score 0):

`NumberFormatException` occurs when you try to convert empty string to an integer.
You can save your code from this crash by check empty values like this:

```
if(!height.trim.isEmpty()){
    height_int = Integer.parseInt(height.trim());
} else {
    height_int = 0;
}
```

You can also use `try/catch` block to avoid crashing like this:

```
try{
    height_int = Integer.parseInt(height.trim());
catch(NumberFormatException e){
    height_int = 0;
}
```